# Linq - Question concerning the 'Any' method

Tags: linq

Assume I have the following query against the AdventureWorks DB:

```
var result = from customer in Customer
    where customer.CustomerAddress.Any (ca => ca.Address.City == "Dallas")
    select new
    {
        customer.Individual.Contact.FirstName,
        Addresses = customer.CustomerAddress
    };
```

This query will return all customers who live in Dallas. However, I'm not sure why it works. I know the 'Any' method returns a Boolean depending on whether any of the rows in the sequence satisfy the predicate. But used in this way, it appears it's actually returning a sequence of rows that do satisfy the predicate. I guess I'm not sure exactly what's happening here.

However, used in the following way, it's easy to understand how 'Any' is working:

```
var result = Customer.Any (c => c.CustomerAddress.Any (ca => ca.Address.City == "Largo" ) );
```

This returns false because no customers live in Largo.

Comment: What's the point you do not understand? Is it the first example returning rows and the second one boolean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first query can be read as

> Return all customers who have any
>   addresses in Dallas.

The response or result in the query is "here are those customers." The first query, the `Any` is strictly against the addresses. So customers that have *addresses that satisfy the `Any`* are returned.

The second query as

> Do I have any customers who have any
>   addresses in Largo?

The result is either yes or no (true or false). You have applied the `Any` to *both* the addresses *and* and the results of the `Any` on addresses. So the first part of the query is "filter by customers with addresses in Largo" and the second is "now all I want to know is if I have any such customers."

Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 4):

`Any` returns a bool, but it's being fed to the `where` clause. The `where` clause takes a boolean expression, applies it to each item in a sequence, and returns those items where the expression is true. So in the extension method syntax, your query translates to:

```
var result = Customer
             .Where(customer => customer.CustomerAddress.Any(ca => ca.Address.City == "Dallas"))
             .Select(customer => new { /*...*/ });
```

Your second example is almost exactly the same, except that it uses an outer `Any` in place of the `Where`. Here it is, formatted to match the code above:

```
var result = Customer
             .Any(c => c.CustomerAddress.Any(ca => ca.Address.City == "Largo"));
```

Simplifying further, it becomes even more clear what's happening:

```
var result1 = Customer
              .Where(customer => customer.HasAnyAddressHere);

var result2 = Customer
              .Any(customer => customer.HasAnyAddressHere);
```

We see that the `Where` clause is what's really driving your first query. You could write it in English as:

> Give me all the customers who have at least one address in Dallas. Ignore their other addresses. If a customer has no addresses in Dallas, filter him/her out of the results.

As you can see, this is asking for a list of customers. The second one works out to:

> Is there at least one customer who has at least one address in Dallas?

This is a yes/no question, so it returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a list of rows that do satisfy the predicate because you are using the `Any` method as a where clause to a `select` statement, which will select a list of rows.

So your first example says 'select all customers who have an address where the address' city is equal to Dallas'. `Any` isn't returning a list of rows (it is just acting as a condition to the where clause), the `select` statement is.

Answer (score 1):

The where statment is evalutated for every element in Customer (a yes or no about each customer).  So you are getting all of the customers who have Any address city = Dallas.

The second statment specifically says tell me if any customer has an address city = Largo. (yes or no)

Answer (score 1):

- For each `customer` in `Customer`
- When the collection of `CustomerAddresses` of `customer` has at least one `Address` with a `City` field that matches `"Dallas"`
- Select "The first name and collection of addresses of the customer".

Answer (score 1):

Here're both of your examples rewritten in method syntax (first one is in mixed syntax in your example, second is already in method)

```
    IEnumerable result = Customers
    .Where(c => c.CustomerAddress.Any(ca => ca.Address.City == "Dallas"))
    .Select(c=> new { FirstName = c.Individual.Contact.FirstName, Addresses = c.Addresses};

    //vs

    bool result = Customers.Any (c => c.CustomerAddress.Any (ca => ca.Address.City == "Dallas" ) );
```

See the assignments? First statement ends with Select => returns enumerable. Second ends with Any => returns bool